# Why is this code depending on `withFilter` or is this a bug?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am working with cats on a project and can't figure out why this strange compiler error occurs in this code:

## with `:Int` it doesn't compile

```
scala> :paste
:paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Test {
  def exec[F[_]: cats.Monad] = for {i: Int <- cats.data.EitherT.fromEither[F](Right(0))} yield i
}

^D
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:12: error: value withFilter is not a member of cats.data.EitherT[F,E,Int]
  def exec[F[_]: cats.Monad] = for {i: Int <- cats.data.EitherT.fromEither[F](Right(0))} yield i
```

## without `:Int` it does compile

The fix to this error is to simply not explicitly annotate the left hand argument of the `<-`. Thus just leave off the type hint `: Int` as in here:

```
scala> :paste
:paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Test {
  def exec[F[_]: cats.Monad] = for {i <- cats.data.EitherT.fromEither[F](Right(0))} yield i
}

^D
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

warning: there was one feature warning; for details, enable `:setting -feature' or `:replay -feature'
defined object Test
```

## for reference

### dependencies

```
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0"
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-macros" % "1.1.0"
"org.typelevel" %% "cats-kernel" % "1.1.0"
```

### `sbt about`

```
sbt:cats-eithert-problem> about
[info] This is sbt 1.1.4
[info] The current project is ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/isaias/Projects/cats-eithert-problem/"), "root") 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.5
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaAppPackaging, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.JavaServerAppPackaging, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jar.ClasspathJarPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.jar.LauncherJarPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.scripts.AshScriptPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.scripts.BashStartScriptPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.scripts.BatStartScriptPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.systemloader.SystemVPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.systemloader.SystemdPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.systemloader.SystemloaderPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.systemloader.UpstartPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.debian.DebianDeployPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.debian.DebianPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.debian.JDebPackaging, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerSpotifyClientPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.jdkpackager.JDKPackagerDeployPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.jdkpackager.JDKPackagerPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.linux.LinuxPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmDeployPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalDeployPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.windows.WindowsDeployPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.packager.windows.WindowsPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.4
```

### `sbt console`

```
sbt:cats-eithert-problem> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
```

## Question

Does anybody know why this code depends on `withFilter` only when it is being annotated explicitly with the corresponding type or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

for comprehension is compiled to combination of `flatMap`, `map` and `withFilter`. `withFilter` is used for the `if` clause of the for comprehension, but even when there is no `if`, `withFilter` is still generated - see [explanation at better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for)

Comment: This explains why this code would "in general" depend on `withFilter` and thanks for the links which helped me now to understand why this is happening. But i am still puzzled, why is the annotated version of the code provoking the issue and the non annotated version not? The `README.md` explains the issue on a non annotated example. As far as i understand it right now the issue should come up with or without the  type annotation. I will clarify my question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The desugared code looks different for both cases.

## `sbt console` with `-Xprint:typer`

After adding `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xprint:typer")` into the `build.sbt` it was possible to print out the desugared code on the `sbt console`:

### without `: Int`

```
def exec         [F[_] >: [_]Nothing <: [_]Any](implicit evidence$1: cats.Monad[F]): cats.data.EitherT[F,Nothing,Int] = cats.data.EitherT.fromEither[F]
  .apply[Nothing, Int](scala.`package`.Right.apply[Nothing, Int](0))(evidence$1)
  .map[Int](((i: Int) => i))(evidence$1)
```

### with `: Int`

```
def <exec: error>[F[_] >: [_]Nothing <: [_]Any](implicit evidence$1: cats.Monad[F]): <error>                          = cats.data.EitherT.fromEither[F]
  (Right(0)).<withFilter: error>((
    (<check$ifrefutable$1: error>: <error>) => 
      <check$ifrefutable$1: error>: @scala.unchecked match {
        case (<i: error> @ (_: Int)) => true
        case _ => false
      }
    )
  )
  .<map: error>(((i: Int) => i))
```

However, i still don't know why the explicit case adds this `withFilter` though. It seems like the strategy inside the compiler is to **NOT** trust the explicit type annotations given by the programmer.

## seems to be intended

[Here is some piece of reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) that a coworker shared with me which shows that usually everything is handled as a pattern on the LHS of the generator.

> A *generator p <- e* produces bindings from an expression *e* which is matched in some way against pattern *p*

Now I am pretty sure this is intended and not a bug, although the case where the pattern is just an identifier is an optimisation is not documented in the given reference it is visible on a smaller example:

### without `: Int`

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e "for { i <- Option(0) } yield i"
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd2652417036573431085.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>(): <$anon: AnyRef> = {
          $anon.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        scala.Option.apply[Int](0).map[Int](((i: Int) => i))
      };
      {
        new $anon();
        ()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### without `: Int`

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e "for { i: Int <- Option(0) } yield i"
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd7960547396256503452.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>(): <$anon: AnyRef> = {
          $anon.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        scala.Option.apply[Int](0).withFilter(((check$ifrefutable$1: Int) => (check$ifrefutable$1: Int @unchecked) match {
  case (i @ (_: Int)) => true
  case _ => false
})).map[Int](((i: Int) => i))
      };
      {
        new $anon();
        ()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the generated code tries to remove non-Int members from the collection